# Ensure Virtual Address is at the start of a page

Tags: virtual-memory

Why does the IF condition checks if the Virtual address pointing at  `str` is found at the start of the page?

```
int main () {
char *str ;
str = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*4);
if ( ((int)str) & 0x00000FFF) != 0) return 0; // ensure the VA is ..
// at the start of a page
strcpy ( str ,"1234567890") ;
printf ("str=%s", str ) ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't, unless the assumption it makes is true.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That is what I want to know.. Why are we checking with 0xFFF? I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get some page-aligned pointer (to some freshly allocated new segment of your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)), use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (or [posix_memalign(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html)....)

To find the size of a page (often, but not always, 4Kbytes) use [getpagesize(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) or preferably [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) with `_SC_PAGE_SIZE`. So your code is wrong if a pointer does not fit into an `int` (this is likely, prefer `intptr_t`) or if the page size is not 4K.

See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), e.g. query the virtual address space of process of pid 1234 with `cat /proc/1234/maps` and/or use the [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) command.

BTW [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) usually don't return a page-aligned pointer (so your `str` often won't satisfy the test `( ((int)str) & 0x00000FFF) != 0)` ...)